# Can I turn off Markdown in Trello?

Tags: trello, markdown

I would prefer not to use Markdown in the Card Descriptions in Trello as I often use include words that contain underscores.  Is there a setting to turn Markdown off?

Answer (score 12):

You cannot disable Markdown in card descriptions in Trello. However, Markdown allows you to use backslash escapes to generate literal characters which would otherwise have special meaning in Markdown’s formatting syntax. For example, if you wanted to surround a word with literal underscores, you can use backslashes before the underscores, like this:

```
\_literal underscores\_
```

The output would be:

```
_literal underscores_
```

Comment: Yes, but it is not fun, when you are copy-paste few such descriptions from another source and you must go through each manually to make it readable.

Answer (score 2):

[Trello now lets you do code blocks:](http://help.trello.com/article/821-using-markdown-in-trello)

````
```
your unformatted text here
```
````

Answer (score -1):

I use workaround [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) with this css code - of course it does not work in mobile applications :-)

```
.card-detail-item-block * {
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: That would not solve the problem of underscores being interpreted as italic formatting. CSS might be able to turn the font back to normal, but it can't restore the missing underscores.

Comment: Of course not solve it whole - I write only what I use for workaround. 

Comment: Generally, on [se] one posts answers that actually answer the question asked, not tangential bits of advice.